# modifying vector returned by reference

Tags: c++

Why size of below vector is 0?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class A
{

    public:
        vector<int> T;
        const vector<int>& get(){
            return T;
        }
        void print(){
            cout<< " size is "<<T.size();
           // cout<<" \nelements are %d "<<T[0];
        }
};
int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
   A ob;
   vector<int> temp = ob.get();
   temp.clear();
   temp.push_back(3);
    temp.push_back(5);

   ob.print();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: By any chance, did you mean `vector<int>& get() const` instead of `const vector<int>& get()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because nothing happened to it. It's still empty.

You made a copy of the vector in `temp`, and you modified the copy, and not the original class member. You should use a reference:

```
 vector<int> &temp = ob.get();
```

Since you are returning a reference from `get()`, you have to assign it to a reference. If you don't, you're just making a copy of the object.

EDIT: Also, change `get()` to return a mutable reference, rather than a `const` reference.

Comment: Note that `get()` is returning a **const** reference, which cannot be assigned to a **non-const** reference. The signature of `get()` needs to drop the `const` on the return value in order for the above code (which is the correct solution for this problem) to compile correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You are not modifying the `vector` that is inside of the `A` class.  `get()` returns a (**const!**) reference, which you are then assigning to a *non-reference* variable, so a *copy* of the `vector` is being created.  You are then modifying the copy but printing out the original.

You need to do this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        vector<int> T;

        vector<int>& get(){
            return T;
        }

        void print(){
            cout << " size is " << T.size();
           // cout << " \nelements are %d " << T[0];
        }
};

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 

   A ob;
   vector<int> &temp = ob.get();
   temp.clear();
   temp.push_back(3);
   temp.push_back(5);

   ob.print();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems.

First, your `A::get()` method returns a const reference to its member. You cannot modify the vector through a const reference.

Second, you're modifying the `temp` vector that is just a copy of the returned value.